# Autolayout Issue with Multiple Button Aligned Horizontally & Vertically with a Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, storyboard

Please look at the ScreenShot attached for `wCompact|hRegular` for different screens, I am trying to make it working since hours but not getting any success. My requirement is that at the top there would be a label with some predefined margin. Although the Label content would render at the runtime, but I know the content size, so `resizable label` isn't needed actually I think. Now there would be three row at equal distance. In first and third row, there would be two buttons with equal height and width and in second row there would be button aligned horizontally. I have set the buttons image and text in storyboard. Control Alignment are set to Horizontal | vertical. Constraints for label are:
`Pinned top space to superview, leading and trailing space equals to:8(superview), height equals:90`.
Constraints for Button(View Transactions) are:
`top space to label, bottom space equals to:8(New Launches Button) leading and trailing space equals to:8(superview) and 8(Place Request Button) respectively, and equal width and height for all buttons.`
Looks fine for 4.7 and 5.5 But not satisfied with the output for smaller screens. As u can see resizing of buttons image not working properly(Larger space between button's image and text). One more thing is I don't wanna set the height of the label, cause it seems like a wrong practice in AutoLayout. Any help would be much appreciated.[image][image: For label]
[image: For Button]

Comment: For the smaller screen you'll probably have to make the text smaller... autolayout isn't quite smart enough to figure that out.

Comment: are you setting the content hugging and compression priorities? why are you pinning the height instead of letting it be intrinsic?

Comment: How would I do that @I'L"I plz explain, In Label I can use the autoshrink property but how would I do that in Button.

Comment: @Wain: No I didn't set that, updated the screenshot. Guide please, still learning AutoLayout.

Comment: because of the 90 to top constraint of your label that make your button cant resize properly, u might want to use code for that (like 20% of the current view height) or force the button height with `greater than or equal` and lower the priority of the label's top constraint, then the button height wont drop below a predefined height

Comment: @Tj3n: How to set that in storyboard. Should I have to set multiplier= 0.4

Comment: `multiplier` is for force size of 2 different view right?, i dont think it do anything here, u can create `aspect ratio` for the button as mention below, but remember to lower the priority of the top label constraint to 999 so it wont overlap each other

Comment: Use stackview for the rows.

Comment: @Bhavuk Jain: can't, have to support iOS 8 too.

Comment: @Tj3n:  didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Aspect Ratio for the Buttons, not just the equal width and height. In that case auto layout wont shrink the images.

Answer (score 0):

Really you should put this into a scroll view so that if the height is too great the user can still see everything by scrolling. You should also not set static heights on labels, you should allow the intrinsic content size to apply.

Add a subview to your new scroll view. Pin the width of this subview to the width of the scroll view. Do not pin the height.

Add all of your buttons and labels to this new subview. Pin them to the edges of the view and allow the intrinsic content sizes to apply limits. Set various items to have equal widths and heights. Do not set explicit heights or widths (do everything by proportion or equality so auto layout can choose good sizes).

Comment: It can be the other way, ll try if it won't work. But what if I want to resize the elements of a View according to the screen-size. Cause, I think that is the main idea behind AutoLayout.

Comment: not really, auto layout can determine size, labels can auto scale down font size

Comment: Actually here in my case, I know the content size of my Label. Hardly it would be 10-15 words, What I am worried for is Buttons.

Comment: why do you want to scale the content down? If anything you should design for small and then decide how to scale up. You can also set different font sizes for different size classes.

Comment: sorry wain, what do u mean by the scaling content down.

Comment: you should be looking to set the width and allow the full height to be calculated, worrying about aspect ratios and layout flow if items are too big. start with the smallest screen you support and work up, don't start big and work down.